# Get Windows Documents Folder Path with Actionscript

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to ActionScript and Flash.
I am really a .NET developer.
I have been asked to modify a flash application that runs on Windows.
Currently it uses hard coded paths. My customer wants it to use the windows document folder for the current user.
Does ActionScript have a method to get the documents folder path?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Flash. When run locally flash has very restricted access. Basically just enough to get some external resources. How ever the AIR runtime was designed to provide more access to the underlying OS. What you need is [`flash.filesystem::File.userDirectory`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#userDirectory).